# WP menu messed up on 1 computer on Chrome, other computer with Chrome is fine

Tags: wordpress

On 1 computer, my WP menu looks like this:

[image]

On another computer with the same browser (Chrome), it looks fine:

[image]

I have already deactivated all browser add-ons on the browser where it gets messed up, but it wouldn't help.

How could I investigate what causes this mess?

Thank you!

Edit:

1. In a new incognito tab, the problem is not present.
2. I have tried application->clear application data (including third party cookies) as suggested, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Try to clear cache from inspect element > application > clear site data.

Answer (score 0):

I have first @VickyP 's suggestion.
It still didn't work.
Then I disabled AdBlock, and it worked.
I am not sure if it was a combination of VickyP's suggestion and diasabling AdBlock on this site, but it works now.